# Wordpress Gravity Forms Validate Field Entry Against CSV File

Tags: wordpress, validation, csv, gravity-forms-plugin

Forgive my ignorance, I am teaching myself as I go along.

I want my employees to enter an invoice number into a form, and then validate that invoice number against a .csv file that is uploaded to Wordpress.  Ideally, I would like it to pull another field as well, almost like a vlookup.

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with? You are likely to get better answers if you show more effort to solve your problem.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't even know where to start.  I have looked at numerous plugins but have not found any that do what I am looking for.